# How to groupby one column with 3 conditions in multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, string, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe, where i need to apply below condition

1. Check if colA > 0
2. If it is, search for string "recycled" in colB and compare if its present in colC
3. If it satisfies, its true else false

dataframe:

```
     Temp       colA     colB             colC

     ob1        50       HDP              HDP
     ob1        50       HDP recycled     HDP
     ob1        50       HDP              HDP
     ob2        0        PE               PE
     ob2        0        PE               PE
     ob3        30       PE recycled      PE recycled
     ob3        30       PE               PE recycled
```

output:

```
     Temp       colA     colB             colC           output
     ob1        50       HDP recycled     HDP            Anomaly
     ob2        0        PE               PE             Pass
     ob3        30       PE recycled      PE recycled    Pass
```

code i tried:

```
     f=pp.groupby('Temp')['colB'].apply(lambda x: 
     x.str.contains('Recycled').any()).map({True:'Pass',False:'anomaly'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Rank function

```
data['Rank'] = data.groupby('Temp')['output'].rank(method='dense',ascending=True)
data['Final'] = data.groupby('Temp')['Rank'].rank(method='first',ascending=True)
```